# PHP Selectbox function not working quite right?

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a table teamtrack_activity that holds id and activity_name.

I have table teamtrack_entry that holds all team daily entries.  This table has a field "activity_id" that I want to store the teamtrack_activity id.  I have this part working.

However I am having 2 issues:

1. Displaying activity_name instead of id.  When I try to do this then activity_name gets passed and this of course doesn't work.
2. When I go back to edit the entry it does not show the value in the database.  It just shows the select box anew.

> ```
>    if ($key == "activity_id")
>
>   {
>
>     $query="SELECT id, activity_name FROM teamtrack_activity Order By id";
>
>     $res = sql_query($query);
>
>     if ($res === FALSE)
>
>     {
>
>       trigger_error(sql_error(), E_USER_WARNING);
>
>       fatal_error(FALSE, get_vocab("fatal_db_error"));
>
>     }
>
>     $select_options["entry.$key"] = array();
>
>     for ($i = 0; ($row = sql_row_keyed($res, $i)); $i++)
>
>     {
>
>       $select_options["entry.$key"][$row['id']] = $row['id'];
>
>     }
>
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$select_options["entry.$key"][$row['id']] = $row['id'];
```

into

```
 $select_options["entry.$key"][$row['id']] = $row['activity_name'];
```

to get a dropdown with the activity ame, which submit the activity ID for your script.

Based on your comment;
It might be the parsing of your $select_options.

In a foreach loop you would want to

```
foreach($select_options["entry.$key"]) as $key => $label)
  {
  echo "<option value=".$key.">".$label."</option>";
  }
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  It sends the activity_name, and activity_id is INT so it reverts to 0.

Comment: That is odd. That would mean that the option you are pulling from the database do not have an ID? Note that I am parsing id, not activity ID. Oh.. Wait a sec, will adjust

Comment: I get what you are saying but don't understand how the foreach statement fits into the code.

Comment: I cannot see where you actually produce the dropdown. It is not show. So I gave an example of how you would have to code the dropdown. I am sure it is somewhere further down your script.